# How to remove trailing '$' character

Tags: line-truncation, lines, truncate-lines

I'm very new to Emacs. Emacs renders all lines with `$` appended. I want to remove them. I think Emacs is visualizing a new line character as `$`, so I searched for options related to `newline` or `whitespace`. But there are so many similar options, I couldn't tell what options I should modify.

Answer (score 1):

See the Emacs manual, node [Line Truncation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Line-Truncation.html):

> As an alternative to continuation, Emacs
> can display long lines by “truncation”.  This means that all the
> characters that do not fit in the width of the screen or window do not
> appear at all.  On graphical displays, a small straight arrow in the
> fringe indicates truncation at either end of the line.  On text
> terminals, this is indicated with `$` signs in the rightmost and/or
> leftmost columns.
>
> Horizontal scrolling automatically causes line truncation.  You can explicitly enable line truncation for
> a particular buffer with the command `M-x toggle-truncate-lines`.  This
> works by locally changing the variable `truncate-lines`.  If that
> variable is non-`nil`, long lines are truncated; if it is `nil`, they
> are continued onto multiple screen lines.  Setting the variable
> `truncate-lines` in any way makes it local to the current buffer; until
> that time, the default value, which is normally `nil`, is in effect.
>
> If a split window becomes too narrow, Emacs may automatically enable
> line truncation.  See Split Window, for the variable
> `truncate-partial-width-windows` which controls this.